# How do I link yaml-cpp in my CMakelists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml, yaml-cpp

So I currently have a project structure that looks like this and there is a cmakelists.txt in every directory:

```
/app
    /source
          /myApp
                /<file where I want to use yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
          /lib
              /yaml-parser(yaml-cpp)
```

When I run out of source builds without including any mentions to yaml-cpp, it compiles the whole directory no problem(the examples of the yaml-cpp provided are compiled). However, when I try to add "yaml-cpp/yaml.h" the compiler says there's no such file or directory. I'm wondering where and how I link my project and yaml-cpp. I  currently have not made any changes to the yaml-cpp cmakelists.txt https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp

Answer (score 0):

You ought to `add_subdirectory` to your root `CMakeLists.txt` and build `yaml-cpp` target. Then you'll be able to link w/ it. Just add `yaml-cpp` to the list of `target_link_libraries` of your binary.